# Ubuntu 17.10 volume control does not work

Tags: sound, 17.10, volume-control

I just upgraded to 17.10 from 17.04, now the sound volume control does not work.  I can hear sound, but cannot control volume, even I completely "mute" the sound from the top-right system menu, it is still playing.

I can control volume inside the playing application, e.g. chrome or smplayer, but the system volume control does not work at all.

Also, from the system settings application, there is no sound device listed at all.

Comment: This problem is fixed by a new installation.   I found that in all my previous experiences, upgrading ubuntu *always* leave some rough edges that is very hard to fix until I completely reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

had a similar problem on kubuntu, found this

https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php/72510-No-audio-volume/page2
and is a hard to find known problem
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ArtfulAardvark/ReleaseNotes/Kubuntu#Known_Problems

> editing `/etc/pulse/default.pa` and commenting the last 3 lines:
>   
>     `#.ifexists module-switch-on-connect.so
>     #load-module module-switch-on-connect
>     #.endif`
>
> seems to solve the issue in some cases.